# Integer comparison problems

Tags: java, android

I use ADT to write the code below and have some problems with comparing two Integers.
Here is the source code.

```
if(longCount == Tsleep)
    Log.d("count", "=:"+longCount);
else if (longCount < Tsleep)
    Log.d("count", "<:"+longCount);
else if(longCount > Tsleep)
   Log.d("count", ">:"+longCount);
longCount++;
```

The value of "Tsleep" is 396.
And the result is as follow.

[image]

It seems like it never runs into "if(longCount==Tsleep)" statement.

Does anyone know what's wrong with it?
Please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Are longCount and Tsleep Integers object or primitive data type ?

Comment: They are Integer objects.

Comment: Where is the source code? I dont see any.

Comment: I upload the source code as images. I could see that.

Comment: @user3138776 You should post it as text so that it's easier to copy and compile it instead of having to type it.

Comment: @user3138776 So `==` will compare their references and not their `intValue();`, while `<` and `>` will unbox those values.

Comment: OK. I change the code as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the "==" operator on objects. If you do integer1==integer2 on objects you test, if integer1 and Integer2 are the same object not if the have the same value!

If you want to know if they have the same value you have to use integer1.equals(integer2).

Answer (score 3):

If these variables are objects, meaning they're [`Integer`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), then `==` works for numbers between [-128,127]. You might want to look at the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) for further (important) information:

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the
>   range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127
>   (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing
>   conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

Answer (score 1):

If those are Integers not ints - use equals instead of == :]

Comment: So why cannot use == for comparison? Is there any wrong with it?

Comment: @user3138776 Because these are *objects* and not primitives. Usually `==` compares references, not values held in them.

Comment: @user3138776 -  because if the numbers are between -128 and 127, Integer stores  these numbers in a local cache and uses them. if numbers are >127 / <(-128), then it returns a new integer.